# Access denied for user 'hp'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in SpringBoot application

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

Trying to connect with MySQL server with my SpringBoot application but facing above issue, can someone suggest?

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myblog
spring.datasourse.username=Admin
spring.datasourse.password=Admin

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dailect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Error as per below

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'hp'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:446) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:239) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:188) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at co
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says user "hp" but your properties say user "Admin". Also the password doesn't match. Your applications is using the wrong credentials. That both passwords have very bad quality for security is a different issue.

Comment: I have changed my system name hp to root but still in error its reflecting as hp..
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'hp'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130) l-

Comment: Still the same problem. It is not using the user from the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the spelling mistake of datasource:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update  
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true   
spring.datasource.username=root  //your db user name  
spring.datasource.password=root  //your db user password 
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect  
#If your MySql version 5 then use MySQL5Dialect
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database=mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo alert!!

```
datasourse -> datasource
dailect -> dialect
```